# getElementById can't find rendered div

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, android-pay

I have this in the function for the success handler from Google Wallet (for digital goods):

```
var elem = document.getElementById(div1);
```

I checked with the debugger and the value of the variable `div1` is the same as the `id` of the div that I see with the 'inspector' (in Firefox) so I know that it's rendered. Besides, the page is shown, and only after clicking a button does the Google Wallet popup appear.

So why is `elem` null? (And how do I solve this?)

Comment: Is this executing before the div has been rendered?

Comment: " the value of div1 is the correct name", what do you mean by value and name? what is the value of div1?

Comment: As I wrote in the question - as far as I can tell it _has_ been rendered (see question). If I'm misunderstanding what I see in the debugger - please correct me.

Comment: @Sergio The value of the variable `div1` is the name that appears as the `id` of the div I'm looking for. - So there is already such a div rendered.

Comment: Ok, can it be a scope issue? where do you use `div1`? inside a function, is it global? showing more code would help you.

Comment: @Sergio `div1` is global. And as I said - the value is correct.

Comment: are you sure it is null? maybe you are trying to call a method on `elem` that doesn't exist? Just throwing this out there...

Comment: @jlars62 Thanks. But the debugger shows null.

Comment: does it work if you write div1's value manualy? (I just give suggestions since I can't see more code.)

Comment: I don't know if it's just a typo here, but shouldn't div1 be in quotes? document.getElementById("div1")

Comment: @meobyte It's a variable.

Comment: @Sergio Hmmm. How do I do that? But that actually is not the problem. The problem is `elem`.

Comment: I mean write the variable's value with quotes in the code and run the page. If it's possible. You don't provide more code so I think about simple/basic ideas.

Comment: @ispiro He means trying this. If `div1 = "someId"`, then try `var elem = document.getElementById("someId");`

Comment: Do you mean div1 has gotten the element by id already? var div1 = document.getElementbyId("foo") Because if so, I'd imagine you'd only need to do var elem = div1

Comment: please show more code.

Comment: is that `div1` dynamically generated?

Comment: @ispiro, can it be a double id somewhere?

Comment: @ispiro, did you fix this?

Comment: @Sergio Finally I did thanks to your help (in your comment that I now upvoted). See my answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a comment by Sergio I found that the value of the variable was *not* the correct one - instead of being "ABC" it was "ABC ". (-With a space at the end.)

Comment: Happy I was of some help :)

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps a timing issue? Try placing the getElementById call inside SetTimeout a few milliseconds later?...